# Migrating Joomla website to Docker: Do I base my image off PHP or Joomla

Tags: php, docker, joomla, frameworks

I am in the process of migrating a Joomla webapp to Docker. It consist of an Apache server, a MySQL database, and Joomla.

**NOTE:** Although my issue is with PHP and Joomla specifically, it looks like the same applies to any case where one has first-party code intermingled with third-party dependencies, such as with many frameworks, including Django or Wordpress, for instance.

**The Problem:**

Since my code is intermingled within Joomla's own source files, I don't know how to isolate Joomla from my own code, so as to be able to make a minimal base image that does not include it's own copy of Joomla.

The whole idea of migrating to Docker *this exact way* comes from the fact that an [official Joomla image](https://hub.docker.com/_/joomla/) is available. I presume I'm supposed to use it, somehow, but I cannot see any reasonable way to do so without then having two copies of Joomla installed. And, even if I got that taken care off, how do I merge my code into the new "Dockerized" Joomla copy when my code is practically everywhere?

It feels like I am supposed to base my image off the Joomla image, but I don't see how I can do some without then having two copies of Joomla, so I should base off the PHP image? Basically I need to know the next step of the way. I've been stuck on this blocker for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`It feels like I am supposed to base my image off the Joomla image`, i think that assumption is not correct at least at the stage which you are.

You would need to base your image on `php` either with apache or with fpm, depending on what you want to use. You will copy your code in this image and then run it.

You would use joomla image only when your app runs as an extension or doesn't touch the joomla base code. When that is the case you can copy the extension to install your code. If your code is mingled then `joomla` image is of no use to you.

Comment: Right, this was my suspiscion, but it's good to have it confirmed. So what you're saying is that if I were to develop a new Joomla project from scratch, I could use the image?

Comment: Yes, you can do that in that case